# How to add message for visual page render as pdf?

Tags: rerender

When I try to add error message to my Visualforce page by using `<apex:pageMeassages/>` tag, my style not working when `renderAs="pdf"`.

This is my Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="ConsumersClaim__c"  extensions="ConsumerBillController" recordSetVar="ConsumerBillController" renderAs="{!renderas}" applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" showChat="false" >
<apex:pageMeassages/>
<apex:repeat var="consumercl" value="{!consumerClaimList}" >
<head>
  <style>
    my style
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 html code here
</body>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: If you want to thank the answerer up vote  their answer. If it is the correct one then mark it as solved.

Comment: I will you the vote when I verify that the answer is correct. now I try to do as his suggestion.

Comment: Apologize, your comment made it sound like what was suggested worked "this is what I wanna do"

Comment: ohh , sorry @Eric , make you confusing , but that comment I thank for his help to edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my test I found `apex:pagemessage` don't display properly. So

I would suggest use a boolean variable and set this to true based on requirement.

And add css or html for message in VF page and display that.

```
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!isDisplay}" >
  My page message
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Comment: I will try with boolean variable

Comment: It's working !!
thanks again

Comment: @minhnv Most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

thank for your help @Ranta 
 
I found that I was put my apex:pagemessages in wrong position 
this my code

```
<apex:page standardController="ConsumersClaim__c"  extensions="ConsumerBillController" recordSetVar="ConsumerBillController" renderAs="{!renderas}" applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" showChat="false" >
<head>
  <style>
    my style
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<apex:pageMeassages/>
<apex:repeat var="consumercl" value="{!consumerClaimList}" >
 html code here
</apex:repeat>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

now it`s working well 
 any way thank you ! nice guy